# My jQuery page-navigation code to hide/show divs doesnt work, and i cant figure out why exactly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

ive created a little site with a navigation header consisting of a table with 5 elements, each taged with an id. the .content_active class has opacity zero by default and the .content class is not visible by default (display:none;)

'#contact' is the navigation element, when you click it, it does a little animation and then should blend out the current active content (div with class .content_active) and convert it to a .content class element (which is not displayed with css). after that, it should take the div with id contact_content and convert it to a .content_active element (which is beeing displayed by css) and change its opacity from 0 to 1.

But it only decreases the opacity of the current .content_active class to 0, after that nothing happens.. what am i doing wrong?

```
var speed = 200;
$("#contact").click(function(){
$("#contact").animate({opacity:"1"},50, function() {
    $(".content_active").animate({opacity:"0"},speed,function(){
        $(this).removeClass(".content_active").addClass(".content");
        $("#contact_content").addClass(".content_active").animate({opacity:"1"},speed);

    });

});
});
```

css:

```
.content {
position: absolute;
left:50%;
margin-left:-360px;
margin-top: 240px;
width:720px;
display:none;
```

}

```
.content_active {
position: absolute;
left:50%;
margin-left:-360px;
margin-top: 240px;
width:720px;
opacity: 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, was probably sitting infront of it for too long and got blind.

simply forgot to .removeclass(content) of the new element that should be shown before giving it the content_active class.. dear god...